# Why is event returned by event handler initially 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm building a simple React component and am confused about something.  Here's the crux of the code:

```
const handleToggleButtonClick = (event) => {
  console.log('handleToggleButtonClick', event.target.value);
  if (event.target.value !== undefined) {
    const newVal = (event.target.value === 'true');
    setIsFirstButton(newVal);
  }
};

return (
  <ToggleButton value='true' onClick={handleToggleButtonClick}>
    Sample Text
  </ToggleButton>
)
```

When I add the React component to my app and run it, `event.target.value` is initially `undefined`, immediately followed by being `true`.  Given that `value` is hardcoded to `true`, why would it ever be `undefined`?

Comment: Where is the component `ToggleButton` coming from?

Comment: `ToggleButton` is a React Bootstrap element: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/#toggle-button-props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this button has to toggle some state but your storing your initial state via `target.value`.

Why not use:

```
const [toggledState, setToggleState) = useState(true)
```

Then when you fire the event handler just update the state? E.g `setToggleState(!toggledState)`. This will invert the state on every click.

The benefits here is that you don’t have to store state on the toggle then try and mutate it. Secondly you drive your state down your view. Rather than persist upwards and modify (with extra unneeded effort).

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the documentation https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/#toggle-button-props I think there is a misuse of event handler in your components. If you want to use standalone togglebutton then you should listen onChange instead

```
<ToggleButton value='true' onChange={handleToggleButtonClick}>
```

Comment: Thank you BOTH!  It's the new year and my brain isn't yet running on all cylinders!!!

Comment: great that you found your answer. cheer! :)